# How to display quote format by preg_match function?

Tags: post-formats

I have defined `quote` post format for the theme:

```
// Add post-formats for theme
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'quote',
) );
```

After it, I want to display quote from the content. For that, I want to use `preg_match_all` function to search for `<blockquote>Hello World.</blockquote>`

```
if( $format == 'quote' ) {

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
    preg_match( '/<blockquote.*?>/', $content, $matches );
}
```

But it is not working. I want to find blockquote tag and display content inside this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta-character `.` match any character except newline. If you have new lines inside quote, try this:

```
preg_match_all( '#<blockquote.*?>([\s\S]*?)</blockquote>#', $content, $matches );
```

> **Escape sequences:**
>
> `\s` - any whitespace character
>   `\S` - any character that is not a whitespace character

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and if there is any class with blockquote then add in this code:

```
preg_match_all( '/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', $content, $matches );
```

Comment: It says array is empty even if i have quote format in my content.

Comment: Can you please share the blockquote tag? Or the page link so that I can check.

Comment: this is my html format for the blog page.
<div class="is-quote-format">
                                                        <blockquote>
                                                            Love is like a beautiful flower which I may not touch, but whose fragrance makes the garden a place of delight just the same.
                                                        </blockquote>
                                                    </div><!-- // is-quote-format -->

Comment: I have tried my code on your text and it is working.
Please see the code:
$content_demo = '<div class="is-quote-format"> <blockquote> Love is like a beautiful flower which I may not touch, but whose fragrance makes the garden a place of delight just the same. </blockquote> </div>';
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content_demo );
preg_match_all( '/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', $content, $matches );
print_r($matches[1][0]);

Comment: I appreciate. I came up with this solution :
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
            preg_match_all('/<blockquote ?.*>(.*)<\/blockquote>/i', $content, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
            if( ! empty( $match ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="mid-block is-post-format-block">
                <div class="is-quote-format">
                    <?php
                    echo $match[0][0];
                    ?>
                </div><!-- // is-quote-format -->
            </div><!-- // mid-block -->
            <?php
            }